# Showing that R-squared might not be useful in time series data

Tags: time-series, econometrics, r-squared, random-walk

I understand that using $R^2$ in time series models may not be the best as $R^2$ is non-decreasing.

I also read this post: [What is the problem with using R-squared in time series models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101546/what-is-the-problem-with-using-r-squared-in-time-series-models) on the problems with $R^2$

However, is there a mathematical way of proving why $R^2$ may not be the most useful in time series data?

$$R^2 = 1 - \frac {\frac {1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \hat u_i^2}{\frac {1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T (Y_t-\bar Y)^2}$$

Using this formula, I tried to find the probability limit of $R^2$ for a stationary AR(1) regression and a random walk.

Is it right to say that in both a stationary AR(1) regression and a random walk, $$\frac {1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \hat u_i^2$$ converges to 0, 
and thus, the probability limit of $R^2$ is equal to 1?

I am not sure if my method is right. Please advice thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, for a random walk, we indeed have that $R^2\to_p1$, but not for the reason you posit.

Whether for a random walk or a stationary AR(1), 
$$\frac {1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \hat u_i^2\to_p\sigma^2,$$
i.e., the numerator of $R^2$ is consistent for the error variances driving the process $y_t$.

But
\begin{eqnarray*}
   R^2&=&1-\frac{\sum\hat{u}_t^2}{\sum (y_t-\overline{y})^2}\\
   &=&1-\frac{\frac{1}{T}\sum\hat{u}_t^2}{\frac{1}{T}\sum (y_t-\overline{y})^2}\to_p1
\end{eqnarray*}
in the RW case, because it can be shown that (see, e.g., Chapter 17 in [Hamilton](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/5386.html))
$$
\frac{1}{T^2}\sum (y_t-\overline{y})^2\Rightarrow\int_0^1W^\mu(r)^2d r
$$
That is to say, *when scaled by $T^2$*, the totoal sum of squares weakly converges to some functional of Brownian motion - an integral over a squared demeaned BM, to be precise.

However, the more important take-away point here is that this result implies that
$$
\frac{1}{T^2}\sum (y_t-\overline{y})^2=O_p(1)
$$
That is, $\frac{1}{T^2}\sum (y_t-\overline{y})^2$ is stochastically bounded, which means $\frac{1}{T}\sum (y_t-\overline{y})^2$ diverges at rate $T$. Hence, the denominator in the $R^2$ formula "explodes" when the process is a random walk.

Comment: Thank you! In the case of AR(1), is it then right to say that $R^2$ converges to beta? Since $$\frac {1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \hat u_i^2\to_p\sigma^2,$$ and $$\frac {1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T (Y_t-\bar Y)^2\to_p\sigma^2/(1-beta),$$

Comment: Recall the variance of an AR(1) is $\sigma^2/(1-\beta^2)$. So $R^2\to_p\beta^2$.